# 2 WiFi-Nets behind a single SSID, how to connect to a specific one?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, nmcli

My wifi router is sending at both 2,4 GHz and 5 GHz ranges.
I want to connect to a 2,4 GHz WiFi.
However my Ubu 20.04 box always connects to a 5 GHz channel under the common SSID.

I can `sudo iwlist frequency` and see that channels 1 to 13 work under 2,4 GHz.

I can `nmcli -f ssid,bssid   dev wifi` to find out the BSSID of the wifi networks available, but i cannot associate BSSID's with the 2,4 GHz channels seen above.

At the end I want to connect to a specific SSID by doing `nmcli d wifi connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`

Even better would be to setup my pc to always connect to any network under 2,4 GHz.

Any idea how to achieve that?

Thx a lot!

Using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: The solution you're looking for is at the router - two distinct SSIDs - not at the OS. But first think about *why* you want to connect to 2.4GHz for the same network as it really makes no sense. Whenever available 5GHz should be preferred because it tends to be less crowded / have less interference from neighboring networks. Yesterday someone asked a similar question because they were worried about the possibility of paying more for the use of 5GHz... I hope you aren't thinking along the same lines.

Comment: I cannot admin the router. I have to take it as it is. People reported me that the 2,4 GHz network is much more stable and faster. I do not know why, but I wanna try it.

Comment: The 5 gHz band is absolutely faster and, because of interference on the 2.4 gHz band, 5 gHz is always preferred.  No 2.4 gHz connection will offer 802.11AC speeds, that is, up to 2,166 Mbps.

Comment: I Chilli, if 300 devices jump into the 5GHz network and i use the 2,4GHz alone, this is no longer the case.  It is pretty much the case here that the 2,4GHz is better, because all others let their device decide which network.

Comment: If 300 devices, then, sure.